# Jetpack Compose WebView: Softkeyboard Enter Key behaves differently based on number of input fields

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, android-view

I'm encountering behavior in Jetpack Compose WebView where pressing the Enter key acts differently depending on the number of input fields on the loaded webpage.

Here's the issue:

- **Single Input Field:** When only one input field exists, pressing Enter functions as expected, likely simulating a "Done" action.
- **Multiple Input Fields:** With multiple input fields, pressing Enter simply jumps focus to the next field, hindering form submission.

I want Enter key presses to consistently trigger form submission, regardless of the number of input fields.

**Desired Behavior:**

- Upon pressing Enter in the WebView, regardless of existing input fields, I want the form to submit as if the user pressed a dedicated "Submit" button.

**Additional Information:**

- Please advise on potential solutions or workarounds to achieve consistent form submission using the Enter key in Jetpack Compose WebView.
- Any insights into handling key events within the WebView or leveraging libraries for communication between the native app and WebView would be greatly appreciated.
- Upon pressing Enter in the WebView, regardless of existing input fields, I want the form to submit as if the user pressed a dedicated "Submit" button.